# Self capacitance of an isolated object

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, charge, distance

A few times I've been reminded that an object can have self capacitance and it's just not registering with me how this can be so. I'm sure there's a good explanation. Here's the explanation I am usually given but I'm still not grasping that capacitance can exist when there is only one "electrode": -

[image]

The implication of this is that if the outer sphere were massively distant from the inner sphere the formula reduces to: -

Capacitance = \$4\pi\epsilon_0\times a\$ because \$\dfrac{1}{b} = 0\$

**This is used as the argument that the middle object has self-capacitance**

See [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html#c2) as the follow on proof. Maybe I'm being stupid?

---

EDIT to ask a directly related question: -

I've correctly calculated that a 1mm radius ball will possess a so-called "self capacitance" of 0.111pF. If two such balls existed and were placed a million miles away from each other (in an empty universe) would the capacitance between them approximately equal 0.0555pF i.e. half of 0.111pF? This "guess" is based on the capacitance of a 1mm ball to an infinite sphere being 0.111pF and from the infinite sphere to the other ball is another 0.111pF.

Therefore, with 2 capacitors in series of the same value, the net capacitance is halved. I can't believe that this is true but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking wrong, but if you can put charge onto something, it must have a capacitance. But if there is no other electrode you wouldn't be able to put charge on something (how would you apply a voltage to make the charge go there). So maybe it's just the huge distance of the other electrode (earth?) to make the term 1/b negligible.

Comment: Are you looking for something that makes it more intuitive, or for something involving maths that prove it? For the earlier, imagine some cable, to make the voltage change on the other end, you have to push some current through it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about the Wikipedia argument https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Self-capacitance: "Self-capacitance is the amount of electric charge that must be added to an isolated conductor to raise its electric potential by one unit (i.e. one volt, in most measurement systems). The reference point for this potential is a theoretical hollow conducting sphere, of infinite radius, centered on the conductor."

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm hoping for an intuitive answer - I have the maths in the question and I know I'm being stupid in not understanding this fundamental thing - I'm just not seeing something that I should see!!

Comment: @RespawnedFluff No, I understand (he says whilst slowly pulling his hair out) capacitance between two electrodes. I just don't have a warm feeling about the self capacitance of an object that is a gazillion light years from anything else. Basically the math tells you that a 1mm ball has self capacitance of 0.111pF. It will have this capacitance in a universe that is empty apart from itself. Huh now WTF does that mean?

Comment: It seems to me you're basically asking what's the physical/practical relevance of this [theoretical] notion of self-capacitance. Am I right?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff - sorry my previous comment focussed on "stray capacitance" - I see the "self capacitance" paragraph above it now but it's the same as what is in my question. What is self capacitance - how can it be understood intuitively (maybe it can't and I just have to accept the math).

Comment: Of course the capacitance is finite at infinity .This was believe it or not taught at highschool! Think about the earthing stake ,its kind of the same,

Comment: @Andyaka: hm, its probably hard without knowing where exactly the "click" is missing in your mind, but for the ball, it would behave like a cap of that magnitude in a circuit where you pump current into it (or out of it).

Comment: Understanding things with infinity in them is not intuitively possible I think. But the universe wouldn't be empty apart from your small sphere, there is still a second electrode out there, far far away in space. Maybe it's just the name of self capacitance which suggests it would be alone, but it isn't and cannot be as you need 2 electrodes to form a capacitor.

Comment: Well, this notion of self-capacitance is a theoretical one, much like, say, an ideal operational amplifier is; the latter has infinite [open-loop] gain. Here you have a capacitor with infinite distance between plates. When one comes across such idealizations based on thought experiments, the question to ask is not whether it can exist but why it is a useful notion.

Comment: I could look at this as watching the electric field decrease as I take the outer spherical shell and expand the distance from the centre. At infinity, the electric field drops to zero (because the radius term is infinite), but the charge still remains.

Comment: I think the self capacitance is just useful to set a lower bound for the capacitance of a body. This body close to the earth, as in a real situation, will have then a bigger capacitance than the calculated "self" one.

Comment: @Autistic it wasn't taught at my school in fact Michael (Mike) Faraday was in the year below me LOL. Anyway asserting that it was taught at your high school doesn't make it a universal fact - earthing stake??????????????

Comment: @Andyaka  This is probably way beyond my understanding, but does a gold leaf electroscope demonstrate self-capacitance?

Comment: @HandyHowie I'm not really that sure. I don't think so but as this is an area of my knowledge that I feel I'm not confident about then who knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand on my comment, [this notion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Self-capacitance) of self-capacitance is a theoretical one, much like, say, an ideal operational amplifier is; the latter has infinite [open-loop] gain. Here you have a capacitor with infinite distance between plates and the 2nd, reference electrode/sphere also has infinite area. When one comes across such idealizations based on thought experiments, the question to ask is not whether it can exist, but ask why is it a useful notion.

Basically this notion is useful as a first-order approximation to problems where the distance is finite but large. [For example](https://books.google.com/books?id=fP4wBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA172), [image]

"Equation 5.4" there simply estimates the mutual capacitance of two [identical] conductors at large distance as one-half of the self-capacitance.

Similarly, a first-order approximation of the capacitance-to-ground (which is a mutual capacitance) of a conductor (placed at some significant distance from ground) is the self-capacitance of the conductor. Ground here is approximated to have infinite area.

Also worth noting here is that mutual capacitance of two finite-area electrodes differs from their self-capacitance, even with infinite distance between them.

Also, as you probably discovered already, "self-capacitance" is also used (e.g. [in transformer contexts](https://books.google.com/books?id=aN0gBQAAQBAJ&pg=SA15-PA3&dq=self-capacitance)) to refer to the mutual, [parasitic capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_capacitance) of the winding. These two are rather different notions. I don't think the former notion of self-capacitance helps much with estimating the latter in a transformer.

---

Actually, I can prove the last part even here. From Zangwill, *Modern Electrodynamics* (p. 140), the capacitance of a two-conductor capacitor is given by

$$C= \frac{C_{11}C_{22}-C^2_{12}}{C_{11}+C_{22}+2C_{12}}$$

Where \$C_{ij}\$ are the [capacitance coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficients_of_potential); in general, this is a symmetric matrix. So if \$C_{11} = C_{22}\$ and \$C_{12} = 0\$ then \$C=C_{11}/2\$, i.e. the capacitance of the two-spheres [at large distance] is half of the self-capacitance of a sphere.

From [Banerjee](http://www.electrostatics.org/images/ESA_2014_G_Banerjee_et_al.pdf) you can see that the following happens as the distance gets large:

[image]

Those dimensionless capacitance coefficients plotted there are simply:

[image]

which means exactly what I wrote above in terms of the non-dimensionless ones.

Comment: I've added an edit section to my question that asks if it is true that two 1mm balls placed a million miles away from each other (in a part of the universe that is physically empty) will have a mutual capacitance that is approximately half their self capacitance.

Comment: @Andy aka: If you want to see precise calculations, not engineering ones,  (and for spheres rather than circles), you'll have to look at physics paper, for example http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~podgornik/download/Lekner-attraction.pdf See section 2 for large/infinite distance.

Comment: No I don't think so. I think I'll ask if this can be migrated to physics.

Comment: I think you can just ask the last part (your edited-in question) there, since it won't be really a duplicate. I don't know that anyone would want to get into those calculations here. Here's a simpler calculation for equal radii spheres:
http://www.electrostatics.org/images/ESA_2014_G_Banerjee_et_al.pdf

Comment: I think that's a good document but it produces an infinite series and doesn't confidently proclaim much that I could take away in the 2 minutes I was reading it for.

Comment: So you seem to be proving what I thought was a stupid notion (in the edited part of my question) - this appears to be either wrong or has deep implications - could it be that for spheres of 1mm in radius, no matter how far you placed them apart the capacitance is 0.0555pF. If the distance is large you could argue that the shape need not be spherical to get roughly the same answer? Interesting but how true it is I just don't know. I think your work deserves an upvote.

Comment: Assuming the asymptotics from Banerjee hold for other shapes (and they probably do), then yes. I alas haven't studied that much physics to say this whether that's the case off top of my head.

Comment: There's one more thing to add here. For two spheres there are no escaping field lines. However for a capacitor formed by a single sphere and a large/infinte plane (like the "ground"), you do have escaping field lines, so the asymptotics are not the same (that's why you don't get half capacitance vs. ground). See http://users.physics.harvard.edu/~morii/phys15b/lectures/Lecture7.pdf (p. 4) for a diagram.

Answer (score 7):

You have to keep in mind that the whole field of electronics is an abstraction of the underlying physics of charged particles attracting and repelling each other.

Lets look at an isolated ball from this perspective.

Start with neutrally charged ball. There are equal numbers of positively and negatively charged particles on the sphere. They balance each other out.

If we want to make current flow into the ball, we are going to need to push charged particles onto it. This will take work because these charged like-charged particles repel each other. The more charged particles we push onto the sphere, the harder it gets to push more because there is more force repelling the new ones. The more we add to the ball, the more force it takes to add even more charge.

If we make the ball bigger, there is more room for the charged particles to spread out. Therefore, for a given number of charged particles stored on the ball, the amount of force it take to add a given additional amount of charge will be less for a large ball than for a small ball.

The force we are talking about here is voltage, and the size of the ball is its capacitance.

Seen this way, hopefully it makes sense why an isolated object can have capacitance.

A standard electronics capacitor is really just two balls (or more likely plates) placed a certain distance apart from each other. IN the limit where the two balls are infinitely far from each other, the above view still works perfectly- keeping in mind that it will take double the force to move a charged particle from one plate to the other  because you not only have to over come the repulsion of the ball you are adding to, you also have to overcome the attraction from the ball you are taking from. As you move the balls closer together, they start to interact and make it easier to move the charges because the imbalances start to cancel out. The closer the balls get, the less force it take to move a charge from one to the other (or the more charge you can move with a given force). So, as the plates of a capacitor get closer, the capacitance (amount of charge to push between the two plates for a given voltage) goes up!

All the math works out perfectly and flows directly from [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) with the help of some geometry and calculus.

I'd highly recommend this book...

[image]

[Matter and Interactions, Volume II: Electric- and Magnetic Interactions](http://amzn.to/1HdZuSo)

(good paper giving a taste of this approach [here](http://matterandinteractions.org/Content/Articles/circuit.pdf))

It completely changed the way I see wire, batteries, capacitors, & resistors and made so many otherwise confusing things finally make sense. It is all just charged particles attracting and repelling each other.

When you are ready to peek under the covers of inductors and antennas so to see that they are also just charged particles attracting and repelling each other (albeit in relativistic frames), then I'd highly recommend this book...

[image]

[Berkeley Physics Course: Electricity and Magnetism v. 2](http://amzn.to/1GMxR88)

(older edition is in public domain and [free here](http://www.slideshare.net/lmcl92/128728926-electricityandmagnetismberkeleyphysicscoursepurcell))

...which again profoundly changed the way I see the world.

Comment: +1 for Purcell's E&M book. (Berkeley)  I heard they have a new edition out that uses MKS rather than cgs units.

Comment: Agreed! Even though I already have a copy of the 1984 edition and the original is free, I happily played $60 for the [new edition](http://amzn.to/1He6jDA) to get the MKS units and the additional problem sets.

Comment: I've actually looked in Purcell's first, but alas I could not find the basic equation of the two-conductor capacitor that I had to use. Ironically, the [self-advertised as] graduate-level textbook by Zangwill was a bit more "for dummies" in this respect. Purcell does cover coefficients of capacitance (p. 109), but he just never seems to get to that obvious particularization.

Comment: For capacitance & resistance stuff you want to start with M&E II. Written for high school students so super simple without fancy math or vocabulary, but the ideas and explanations are beautiful. Will change your life. I'll try to post a link to a lecture covering this, but the book is the best.  I have extras to lend out if you are anywhere near NYC!

Comment: M&E Lecture on Capacitors is Chapter 20 [here](http://courses.ncsu.edu/py582/common/podcasts/), but not nearly as good as reading the book.

Comment: @bigjosh what book are you talking about that is for high school students?

Comment: @minusatwelfth https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0471078476/ref=dbs_a_w_dp_0471078476

Answer (score 2):

Self capacitance is very real. My favorite example of this is the capacitance of your body. So you should think of the other electrode as ground.  Which here on Earth is never very far away. But if it's further away than the size of the object, the capacitance formula you posted is a decent approximation.  (Well I'm a physicist and have no problem treating the body as a sphere :^)  So try this as a way to measure your self capacitance.

Get out your x10 (10 meg) scope probe, charge up your body by rubbing on some fabric, my chair works fine.  Now with the 'scope set for single shot touch the end of of the probe and look at the decay.   From the time constant determine your capacitance.  (I'm about 200 pF, I am growing a bit of a beer belly)

Comment: @Andyaka, You just need to see ground as the other terminal for the capacitance... even if it's very far away.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer this part of the question:

> I've correctly calculated that a 1mm radius ball will possess a so-called "self capacitance" of 0.111pF. If two such balls existed and were placed a million miles away from each other (in an empty universe) would the capacitance between them approximately equal 0.0555pF i.e. half of 0.111pF?

As you know C=Q/V, i.e. C is the number of Coulombs that will accept the capacitor per each Volt (or a given "effort").

Imagine first that you have a power supply that has the small ball in one of its terminals and the huge ball (infinite sphere) in the other terminal. The two balls are separated by a huge distance and therefore the electric field influence between them can be neglected. While this capacitor charges, the necessary effort for putting charges into the small ball will increase (because the already put charges in the small ball are repelling the new ones). In contrast getting charges from the huge ball is almost free (you might think in terms of charge density). Therefore the capacitance of this capacitor only depends on the small ball. In contrast if the small ball approaches the huge ball, the electric influence between them cannot be neglected anymore. And the capacity of this new capacitor will be bigger than the Cself, which is therefore a lower bound.

For the two small balls the same argument applies. When they are infinitely separated the power supply has to provide an effort to put charges to one of the balls, but also has to provide an effort to get charges from the other small ball. At the end, for a given effort or voltage, the number of coulombs will be the half, therefore C=Cself/2. In the other hand, if the two small balls gets closer the electric influence between them cannot be neglected anymore, and the capacitance will be bigger than Cself/2, which is the lower bound.

Comment: Thanks Roger, so is it a yes, no or a nearly?

Comment: Yes, for a separation of zillion miles the capacitance would be Cself/2. Theoretically it would be very very slightly above this value, but no one could measure the difference I guess (you would need too many digits).

Comment: Thanks - that deserves an upvote because it's starting to gel and my mind is starting to accept the stupid sphere at infinity!!

Comment: Great!! When spheres are separated by infinite they don't interact, electrically but you still you need to provide effort to get charges from one of them and more effort to put it into the other one.

Answer (score 0):

\$c_{11}\$ is the intrinsic partial capacitance, which is not the same thing as self capacitance of the conductor in isolation, because it takes into consideration the surrounding geometry. For a system with two conductors but only one charged conductor:

$$Q_1 =V_1c_{11}$$
$$C_1 = c_{11}$$

\$c_{11} =C_{\text{self}}\$ when there are no conductors in the vicinity, otherwise \$c_{11} \gt C_{\text{self}}\$. Similarly therefore \$Q_{11} \gt Q_{\text{self}}\$ because \$Q_{11}\$ is \$Q_{\text{self}}\$ plus the extra charge that is counterinduced on the conductor by charges it induces on the surrounding conductors and \$c_{11}\$ is \$C_{\text{self}}\$ plus the increase in capacitance due to the counterinduction of charge, effectively \$C_{\text{self}}+C_{121}\$

\$V_1\$ is the sum of the potentials from all fields from that point on conductor 1 to inifnity.

For a system with two charged conductors:

$$Q_1 = Q_{11} +Q_{12}$$
$$V_1C_1 = c_{11}V_1 + c_{12}V_2$$
$$C_1 = c_{11} + c_{12}\frac{V_2}{V_1}\tag{1}$$

When both conductors have equal and opposite charge \$Q=c_{11}V_1 + c_{12}V_2 = -(c_{22}V_2 + c_{12}V_1)\$ can be equated to give $${\displaystyle V_{1}={\frac {Q(c_{12}+c_{22})}{(c_{11}c_{22}-c_{12}^{2})}},\qquad \quad V_{2}={\frac {-Q(c_{12}+c_{11})}{(c_{11}c_{22}-c_{12}^{2})}}}$$

Which when substituted into eq.(1) to give the total capacitance of each conductor $$C_1=c_{11} + \frac{V_2}{V_1}c_{12}=c_{11} - \frac{c_{11}+c_{12}}{c_{22}+c_{12}}c_{12}=\frac{c_{11}c_{22}-c_{12}^2}{c_{12}+c_{22}}$$

$$C_2=c_{22} + \frac{V_1}{V_2}c_{12}=c_{22} - \frac{c_{22}+c_{12}}{c_{11}+c_{12}}c_{12}=\frac{c_{11}c_{22}-c_{12}^2}{c_{12}+c_{11}}$$

The mutual capacitance is therefore:

$$C=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{C_1} + \frac{1}{C_2}} =\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{c_{11}c_{22}-c_{12}^2}{c_{12}+c_{22}}} + \frac{1}{\frac{c_{11}c_{22}-c_{12}^2}{c_{12}+c_{11}}}} = \frac{c_{11}c_{22}-c_{12}^2}{c_{11}+2c_{12}+c_{22}}$$

There is also another notation using a capital C defined: \$C_{11} =c_{11} + c_{12}\$ and \$C_{12}=-c_{12}\$ which allows you to do \$C_{11}V_1 + C_{12} (V_1 - V_2)\$ for whatever reason you'd want to represent it in terms of potential differences.

---

It must be remembered that the presence of other conductors that give a counterinduction of charge on conductor 1, or induce a further charge by being inherently charged themselves does not cause the voltage of conductor 1 to change if conductor 1 is grounded because any potential placed on conductor 1 is cancelled out by the potential of the charge that moves onto the conductor from ground. If it is ungrounded you get a situation where V changes and not Q (here capacitance is infinite when the voltage of the applied field is equal and opposite to the voltage of the charge on the conductor) . If it is grounded Q changes and not V (here capacitance is infinite when the inherent charge is 0V, which it is when grounded, but not when connected to a charged conductor i.e. a voltage source.

If you have 1 sphere in the universe, and nothing else, then the self capacitance is the absolute lowest limit on the capacitance of the sphere, and is only based on the geometry of the sphere itself (\$4\pi\epsilon_0\epsilon_r r\$). A smaller sphere has lower capacitance because there's not as much area for the charge to distribute, therefore the electric field for a particular charge on a smaller sphere is greater than the same field from a larger sphere with the same charge.

If you have 2 such spheres and connect them to say a 5V a power supply, the spheres are individually only going to acquire a voltage magnitude of 2.5V, rather than 5V and a Q for 5V, you get 2.5V and a Q for 2.5V, except the potential difference is still 5V, so the capacitance is half. If you have a tiny sphere and a large sphere, the voltage on the tiny sphere will be say -4.999V and the voltage on the large sphere will be 0.001V; you can see how the total capacitance of the system for a given supply voltage is given by the calculation of the two self capacitances in series.

When the spheres are moved closer together, the capacitance of the system can only increase due to the \$c_{11}\$ (intrinsic partial capacitance) and \$c_{12}\$ (mutual partial capacitance) components of mutual capacitance – at some point the opposing field from the opposite sphere is going to be felt, and will lower the potential of the sphere, and vice versa, and this is going to allow even more charge to be move to the spheres. This would be pictured as a mutual capacitance in parallel with the self-capacitance-in-series path.

The introduction of planet earth into the picture gives yet another parallel path consisting of the two mutual capacitances to earth. This would increase the capacitance of the system once again, because it's in parallel. Of course, the system would need to be grounded temporarily so that everything becomes the reference  potential of planet earth, around \$\frac{-500000\text{C}}{710\mu F} = -704\text{MV}\$ I think; except it seems to be less than that because the atmosphere causes it to act as a spherical capacitor, and the voltage of the inner earth sphere drops to 300kV, so it's actually that.

Comment: This isn't an answer - it's a statement of truth but doesn't explain why.

Comment: @AndyAka I updated it a bit