# Capacitance of an isolated solid copper conductor in air

Tags: capacitance

I have been unable to discover anything about isolated conductor capacitance. One approach would surely be to find the formula for an air dialectic coaxial capacitor. The denominator of this formula is the natural logarithm of the ratio of the coax external and internal dimensions.

If we now set the dimension ratio to some large number, say 10000 then we arrive at an approximation of a few picofarads per metre.

Is this a realistic way of estimating a result?

Comment: Show a diagram and some of your theoretical, quantitative derivations from it I'd like to see more about what you are on about here.

Comment: [Self capacitance of an isolated object](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197830/self-capacitance-of-an-isolated-object)

Comment: Ha! This is a thought experiment concerning voltage transmission. Imagine a ten metre isolated copper wire with a means of instantaneously connecting it to a DC battery at the battery end. Assume the battery is grounded to some conducting workbench.  Assume there is a means of testing the voltage at the remote end of the wire. Measure the time from switch-on to battery voltage at the remote end. Assuming my value of self capacitance is approximately correct the voltage wave will of course take longer to reach the voltmeter than five times the wire time constant?

Comment: For a wire of diameter of 1mm at a height of ~ 100 m (conductor plane), Zo should be 600 Ohm (?). Capacitance: C = 7.309e-12 F.